# How to iterate for each loop for duplicate values

Tags: java, selenium, foreach

**What I expect to happen:** The program should find the expected Web Element from the list, click on it, find the contract id and match with the given contract id. If yes, break the loop else click back button and proceed until the conditions are satisfied.

**Actual issue :**
On running this for each loop; the program finds the first web element in the list and it passes the first if condition.  While after clicking the web Element, as the second if condition is not satisfied it gets out of the loop and checks for each loop once again but the program or the code break here and throws error like" stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document ":(

how to get over this error?

Note :-" Where as my required Web Element is 3 rd in the List for the given contract id ".

```
// Selenium Web Driver with Java-Code :-    
WebElement membership = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='content_tab_memberships']/table[2]/tbody"));

List<WebElement> rownames = membership.findElements(By.xpath(".//tr[@class='status_active']/td[1]/a"));
// where rownames contains list of webElement with duplicate webElement names  eg:- {SimpleMem, SimpleMem , SimpleMem ,Protata} but with unique contarct id (which is displayed after clicking webElement)

for (WebElement actual_element : rownames) {
    String Memname = actual_element.getAttribute("innerHTML");
    System.out.println("the membershipname"+  Memname);

    if (Memname.equalsIgnoreCase(memname1)) {
        actual_element.click();  
        String actualcontractid = cp.contarct_id.getText();

        if (actualcontractid.equalsIgnoreCase(contractid)) {
            break;
        } else {
            cp.Back_Btn.click();
            Thread.sleep(1000L);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: you mentioned that program throws error, could you please paste update your question with error? I think you may be facing StaleElemenetReferance - http://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp

Answer (score 0):

After clicking on `row` element, you are navigating away from current page DOM. On the new page, if Contract Id is not matched, you are navigating back to the previous page.

You are expecting that you should be able to access the element from the list [rows] which was present earlier when you performed `foreach` loop. But now that DOM is reloaded earlier elements are not accessible hence the [Stale Element Reference Exception](http://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp).

Can you please try below sample code?

```
 public WebElement getRowOnMatchingMemberNameAndContractID(String memberName, String contractId, int startFromRowNo){
        WebElement membership = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='content_tab_memberships']/table[2]/tbody"));
        List<WebElement> rowNames = membership.findElements(By.xpath(".//tr[@class='status_active']/td[1]/a"));
// where rownames contains list of webElement with duplicate webElement names  eg:- {SimpleMem, SimpleMem , SimpleMem ,Protata} but with unique contarct id (which is displayed after clicking webElement)
        for(int i=startFromRowNo; i<=rowNames.size(); i++){
            String actualMemberName = rowNames.get(i).getAttribute("innerHTML");
            if(actualMemberName.equalsIgnoreCase(memberName)){
                rowNames.get(i).click();
                String actualContractId = cp.contarct_id.getText();
                if(actualContractId.equalsIgnoreCase(contractId)){
                    return rowNames.get(i);
                }else {
                    cp.Back_Btn.click();
                    return getRowOnMatchingMemberNameAndContractID(i+1);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I have used the recursion and additional parameter to handle the previously clicked row. You can call above method with 0 as starting row like-

```
WebElement row = getRowOnMatchingMemberNameAndContractID(expectedMemberName, expectedContractID,0);
```